# Flutter cannot find a native iOS implementation of method

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart, flutter-plugin

I try to return a string from **Swift**'s side of my **Flutter** plugin to **Dart**'s:

```
public class SwiftAMPlugin: NSObject, FlutterPlugin {

    public static func register(with registrar: FlutterPluginRegistrar) {
        let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "aM", binaryMessenger: registrar.messenger())
        let instance = SwiftAMPlugin()
        registrar.addMethodCallDelegate(instance, channel: channel)
    }

    private func getStr(_ call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) {
        result("test");
    }

    public func handle(_ call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) {
        switch (call.method) {
        case "getStr":
            getStr(call, result: result);
            break;
        default:
            result(false);
        }
    }
}
```

On **Dart**'s side:

```
static Future<String> getStr() async {
  try {
      return await _channel.invokeListMethod('getStr');
  } catch(e, s) {
      print(e);
      print(s);
  }
}
```

But it crashes on `getStr` call with error:

```
2020-05-24 00:05:17.547324+0300 Runner[4146:2064989] flutter: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getStr on channel aM)
2020-05-24 00:05:17.552161+0300 Runner[4146:2064989] flutter: #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:154:7)
```

I have a similar implementation for **Android** and it works perfectly.

Where can the problem be?

**P.S.** Imma noobie in **Flutter**, maybe do I need to describe my native method implementation somewhere? Now I just have `switch` block to find required method.

Answer (score 2):

@Шах did you check you `pubspec.yaml`? You should have an entry for iOS like so:

```
plugin:
    platforms:
      ios: 
        package: com.domain.my_lib
        pluginClass: MyPlugin
      android: 
        package: com.domain.my_lib
        pluginClass: MyPlugin
```

Make sure it is the right class and right package. Then do `flutter clean` and `flutter run`.

Comment: It didn't help, unfortunately